# SSH MOTD per User

Tags: shell, unix, ubuntu, ssh, remote-access

After connection to the ssh you get a welcome message that is fed by /etc/motd. Now I would like to have those messages per user but I am not allowed to edit /etc/motd.

So I wonder if there is something possible with ~/.ssh/motd so that those messages will be stored in the users dir. This would be great because every user shall have it's own instructions for the given path-structure.

Does someone know how to solve this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could display the contents of any file (that the user can read) from within a login script.

Comment: You might have better luck at http://serverfault.com/. This is for general programming.

Comment: It should go to http://askubuntu.com/ or http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for all those links. Truly a better place for this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Message of the day" is a cheap way to send a message to all users. If you want to target individual users, you have these options:

1. Send them an email.
2. Edit the login script (look into `/etc/profile` for Bourne shells) and add a line which looks for a per-user message in a certain path and which displays that. Example:

   ```
   test -e /var/motd/$LOGNAME && cat /var/motd/$LOGNAME
   ```

The second approach has the advantage that you can define which path is used (so you can use one which you can write; if you can't write `/etc/motd`, then you can't edit anything in `~/.ssh/` either).

You will need to be `root` to set this up this, of course.

Comment: Yee, that's the usual way. But neither root nor sudo are available. Just from the scope of the user himself.

Comment: Then you will have each user edit their `.profile` to add the line above but with a path that you can write to.